# upload file to multiple hdfs using a single hadoop client

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Basically I can upload a file by typing the command:

**hadoop fs -put filename /path/to/dir**

which will write to the currently configured cluster.

Is is possible if I upload a file to a different cluster using the same client? with commands like:

**hadoop fs -put filename hdfs://cluster2_namenode_ip/path/to/dir**

or some alternatives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works. You have to make sure your hadoop client is of the same version with hadoop on the other cluster. Also you should have connectivity with other cluster's worker nodes.

There are some special cases. If your cluster has namenode ha or kerberos configured you won't get away with just that command; some additional configuration will be needed.

Comment: Agreed with @facha. Another alternative is hadoop's distcp tool

Comment: Hello, may I ask you two question? Which version of hadoop HDFS do you use ? And where do you download the HDFS client java jar package ? I cannot find a valid hadoop HDFS client jar package for 2.7.1 hadoop HDFS.

Comment: If that question goes for me, I've used various (including 2.7.1). There is no special "client" package. You just download (or compile from source) the whole hadoop tar.gz, which includes the client libraries/binaries/scripts.